# Can't run opengl program in other computers.. compiled by Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, opengl

Ok, so I want to run simple opengl program that I've written, on other computers.
I can run it successfully on my machine. It doesn't give any errors.
When I run it on other computer however it says "cannot start application because MSVCR100.dll was not found"
What's the problem? Or maybe I'm doing something wrong?

- I tried both compilations on Visual Studio 2010, Debug and Release.
- executable always have been shipped with glut32.dll in the same directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSVCR100.dll is the C runtime associated with Visual Studio 2010.  In order to run successfully, the other computer needs a copy of that runtime DLL.  It can get it either by installing Visual Studio 2010 on it (not recommended), or installing the [Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=a7b7a05e-6de6-4d3a-a423-37bf0912db84) **(recommended)**.

Note that you must compile your program in Release mode, not Debug mode—a Debug build links against the debug version of the C runtime, for which Microsoft does make a redistributable package.  It is illegal to redistribute the debug runtime DLLs, so if you want to distribute your software and be able to run it anywhere, you need to link against the release runtime libraries.

Comment: So if I want to distribute my program for example, do I need to include glut32.dll and MVC++ 2010 redistributable package or better create an installer that takes care of installing of all these? Is there easier way like just to copy *.exe and glut32.dll? Maybe another compiler?

Comment: opengl32.dll and glut32.dll will be available. You can copy-paste MSVCR*.dll near your .exe, it'll work, but the redistributable package will make sure that the .dll version will be correct regarding the architecture : 32 vs 64, processor, etc.